# Помогите немножко подправить скрипт

Tags: jquery

Скрипт был написан для такой структуры:

```
<div class="catalog">
<img src="img/name12.jpg"/>
<a href="cat/tovar1.html">товар 1</a>
</div>
```

А у меня такая:

```
<div class="title">
<h2 itemprop="name"><a href="cat/tovar1.html" itemprop="url">товар 1</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="miniature">
<img itemprop="image" src="img/name12.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Вот скрипт, который нужно чуть-чуть подправить:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('.catalog img').live('click', function() {
document.location.replace($(this).parent().find('a').attr('href'));
});
});
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуй так:

   document.location.replace($(this).parent().prev('.title').find('a').attr('href'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через jQ будет так:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.miniature img').live('click', function() {
        document.location.replace(
            $(this).parent().prev('.title').find('a').attr('href')
        );
    });
});
```

Должно работать.
А вообще разумней сделать вот такую структуру:

```
<div class="title">
    <h2 itemprop="name">
        <a href="cat/tovar1.html" itemprop="url">товар 1</a>
    </h2>
</div>
<div class="miniature">
    <a href="cat/tovar1.html">
        <img itemprop="image" src="img/name12.jpg"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Без всякого  js.

Comment: мне для seo лишние ссылки убрать нужно.

Comment: @rodion так вы nofollow поставте, или как там..

Comment: Говорят, не совсем надежно, а так наверняка.